# Is it possible to do a Master's and PhD at the same time?

Tags: phd, masters

I am currently in my master's and about to start my research. Is it possible that I can do my research with any institute in Europe or do my Ph.D. at the same time but from different universities?

Comment: Possible, but unlikely. You would need to find the institution yourself, though.

Comment: What is the motivation behind attempting this?

Comment: I know people who have done postdoc and Ph.D. at the same time. doable.

Answer (score 3):

In most European countries you can be considered for a PhD position only if you have already a master in a related field.

I also think that doing a master and a PhD at the same time will be too much work for one person.

Comment: "too much work for one person" - I'll add: if done properly.

Comment: That's usually the case, but I've seen people doing a PhD in Europe without a master's (in a PhD program that normally requires a master's degree). Usually this is not a good idea though; best case scenario, it's too much pressure on the PhD candidate, and the PhD is likely botched.

Answer (score 1):

The other way around is a little more common. People in PhD program do a master in different field within the same university to improve job prospect in industry.

Comment: My understanding is that this is an American thing. Haven't heard or seen anyone with a European PhD doing that, and as far as I know, the structure of a typical PhD in Europe makes it very difficult to do that (if not impossible). My experience and data is limited though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to so this exact same thing. I got accepted onto a PhD program whilst I was still finishing my research masters at the same university. I thought I would be able to finish my analysis and write up for my masters whilst beginning my PhD.

I found out over time that this wasn't going to be physically possible, due to the workload. I risked disrupting all the important things you need to do when starting a PhD by working all hours trying to finish the masters, and it became way too much in the end. Fortunately, there was no requirement to have a masters for my PhD program, and I dropped the masters within 4 months.

So my general advice would be aware that it is going to be extremely difficult work-wise. I have  no idea about your country/field/personality, but I would say that in my field, the fact that I dropped my masters is probably going to make zero bearings in my future career, and so in hindsight was a good choice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the institutions but the expectation is that you are committed on a full time basis to your degree, and the work load is usually commensurate with this expectation.

Finding a thesis director or an academic advisor that will let you spend considerable chunks of time on a different degree is probably not so easy either.  It’s not like you can be at two places at once, so how do you propose to explain to your PhD advisor that you need to leave to work on your MSc or MA project?